# After upgrading AGP version from 4.2.1 to 7.0.0(same with 7.0.1) WorkManger not run jobs after r8 minifying

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-workmanager

After upgrading AGP version from 4.2.1 to 7.0.0(same with 7.0.1) WorkManger not run jobs after r8 minifying(tested on debug and release builds with minifyEnabled = true).
No crash, but in Background tasks inspector job is just queued, but event didn't tried to start.
But it works correctly when minifyEnabled = false.

Tested on WM library versions: 2.5.0, 2.6.0.

Also tested with adding all proguard-rules from:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/work/
but same issue was reproduced.

On 4.2.1 everything works fine.

Maybe issue is related in some way to upgrading Java from 8 to 11 version.

Link to PR with changes:
https://github.com/game-x50/android_client_app/pull/22/files

Thanks.

Comment: Does it create a background crash when WorkManager tries to run jobs or jobs are not run at all?

Comment: No, in background task inspector task is just looks like queued.